# How to flip in famo.us?

Tags: famo.us

How I can do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/2199/) to my Container Surface with famo.us? My container surface looks like this:

```
var input1Fix=new ContainerSurface({
    size:[241,40],
    properties:{
        backgroundColor:'black',
        overflow:'hidden'
    }
});
input1FixModifier= new Modifier({
    origin:[1, 0.5],
    align:[1, 0.5]
});
var mailContainer= new ContainerSurface({
    size:[40,40],
    properties:{
        backgroundColor:'#483f3e',
        overflow:'hidden'
    }
});

var mailContainerModifier= new Modifier({
    origin:[0, 0.5],
    align:[0, 0.5]
});
var mail= new ImageSurface({
    size:[20, 20],
    content:'img/mail.png',
    overflow:'hidden'
});
var mailModifier= new Modifier({
    origin:[0.5, 0,5],
    align:[0.5, 0,5],
    transform: Transform.translate(0, 10)

});
var input1= new InputSurface({
    size:[200,40],
    placeholder:' E-mail:',
    properties:{
        backgroundColor:'#483f3e',
        border:'#483f3e',
        color:'#9d9492',
        overflow:'hidden'
    }
});

var input1Modifier=new Modifier({
    origin:[0.5,0.5],
    align:[0.5,0.5]
   });
```

So, I want when I click on surface that it rotates and changes color. What's the best way to do that?

I'm beginner with famo.us and javascript so, any help is good help. thanks for understanding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[Flipper](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/develop/src/views/Flipper.js)** View and set the back and front using surfaces or views.

To get it to flip horizontally, set the option `direction: Flipper.DIRECTION_Y` as in the snippet below.

```js
define('main',function(require, exports, module) {
    var Engine     = require("famous/core/Engine");
    var Surface    = require("famous/core/Surface");
    var Flipper    = require("famous/views/Flipper");
    var Modifier   = require("famous/core/Modifier");

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    mainContext.setPerspective(500);

    var flipper = new Flipper({
        direction: Flipper.DIRECTION_Y
    });

    var frontSurface = new Surface({
        size : [200, 200],
        content : 'front',
        properties : {
            background : 'red',
            lineHeight : '200px',
            textAlign  : 'center'
        }
    });

    var backSurface = new Surface({
        size : [200, 200],
        content : 'back',
        properties : {
            background : 'blue',
            color : 'white',
            lineHeight : '200px',
            textAlign  : 'center'
        }
    });

    flipper.setFront(frontSurface);
    flipper.setBack(backSurface);

    var centerModifier = new Modifier({
        align : [.5,.5],
        origin : [.5,.5]
    });

    mainContext.add(centerModifier).add(flipper);

    var toggle = false;
    Engine.on('click', function(){
        var angle = toggle ? 0 : Math.PI;
        flipper.setAngle(angle, {curve : 'easeOutBounce', duration : 500});
        toggle = !toggle;
    });
});
require(['main']);
```

```css
.double-sided {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the use of the "double-sided" css I don't see used anywhere ?

Comment: [Offirmo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/587407/offirmo) in the case of this example it would not be needed, because the flipper uses two surfaces. It was a carry over from an example of flipping a single surface using rotation.